# Calling a void async. - Event based pattern, or another method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a class that basically stores files in amazon s3.
Here is what it looks like (simplified)

```
public class S3FileStore
{
   public void PutFile(string ID, Stream content)
      {
          //do stuff
      }
}
```

In my client app, I want to be able to call:

```
var s3 = new() S3FileStore();
s3.PutFile ("myId", File.OpenRead(@"C:\myFile1"));
s3.PutFile ("myId", File.OpenRead(@"C:\myFile2"));
s3.PutFile ("myId", File.OpenRead(@"C:\myFile3"));
```

I want this to be an asynchronous operation - I want the S3FileStore to handle this (i don't want my caller to have to execute PutFile asynchronously so to speak) but, i want to be able to trap exceptions / tell if the operation completed for each file.

I've looked at event based async calls, especially this:
http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rendle/archive/2008/11/04/functional-shortcuts-2-event-based-asynchronous-pattern.aspx

However, I can't see how to call my PutFile (void) method?

Are there any better examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the solution for this question: [Adding cancel ability and exception handling to async code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491842/adding-cancel-ability-and-exception-handling-to-async-code/2491923#2491923) . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `BackgroundWorker` base class might be worth a look, and also the Thread Pool:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate 
    { 
       s3.PutFile ("myId", File.OpenRead(@"C:\myFile1"));
    });
```

This is basically what you would do with the Action/BeginInvoke pattern. With BeginInvoke, you additionally receive an `IAsyncResult` on which you can call `.WaitOne()` to block the current thread until the operation finished, in case you need that. You would trigger a new `BeginInvoke` for every file you'd like to save.

If you need to do this frequently, a more sophisticated version could be to use a Queue in combination with the BackgroundWorker, e.g.:

```
public sealed class S3StoreLikePutFileWorker<TYourData> : BackgroundWorker
{
    private AutoResetEvent WakeUpEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private Queue<TYourData> DataQueue = new Queue<TYourData>();

    private volatile bool StopWork = false;

    public void PutFile(TYourData dataToWrite)
    {
        DataQueue.Enqueue(dataToWrite);
        WakeUpEvent.Set();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        StopWork = true;
        WakeUpEvent.Set();
    }

    private override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        do
        {
            // sleep until there is something to do
            WakeUpEvent.WaitOne();
            if(StopWork) break;

            // Write data, if available
            while(DataQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                TYourData yourDataToWrite = DataQueue.Dequeue();
                // write data to file
            }
        }
        while(!StopWork);
    }
}
```

Depending on how much complexity you need.

The BackgroundWorker supports progress feedback (set `WorkerReportsProgress = true;` in the constructor), and you can also add a custom event to report errors, if that is necessary:

```
// create a custom EventArgs class that provides the information you need
public sealed class MyEventArgs : EventArgs {
   // Add information about the file
}

// ... define the event in the worker class ...
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> ErrorOccured;

// ... call it in the worker class (if needed) ...
if(ErrorOccured != null) ErrorOccured(this, new MyEventArgs(/*...*/));
```